# RelativeLayout's layout_above gives "No resource found" error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
  <ListView
      android:layout_above="@id/btn_4"    <-- this line error: No resource found
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="200dp" />
  <Button android:id="@+id/btn_4"         <-- I declare the id here
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As I understand it, the first time an id is used in a layout xml, it needs to have a + sign in front of it.

From the [Declaring Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) docs:

> The plus-symbol (+) means that this is a new resource name that must be created and added to our resources (in the R.java file).

So, add a '+' to the first btn_4 reference in the ListView layout and you can remove the unnecessary '+' from the android:id attribute in the Button layout.

Answer (score 3):

When you declare relative layouts, you have to use `android:layout_above="@+id/layoutToBeAbove"`

Otherwise, the system does not know what you're pointing at.

This declaration will point at the same resource.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 2):

Declare the `ListView` list_1 **after** declaring the `Button` btn_4 as it tries to reference it in `android:layout_above="@id/btn_4"`.

Comment: XML is a markup language, there is no "execution order", as it is stateless.  It doesn't matter where it is declared, it simply has to have correct markup.

Comment: Eh? XML is what you make of it. I can parse it top-down if I want to (order is maintained). It *does* fix the issue. Imagine if A could declare itself above B and B declare itself above A.